# How to return neural network weights (parameters) values of nnetar function?

Tags: r

I am using nnetar of forecast package for a forecasting modelling of a univariate time series.
i fitted a model for example neural network NAR(p,P) on the series data. now i want to know how can i return the weighs or the best weighs that nnetar estimated??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is explained in `?nnetar`: in the output, the `model` field contains the list of neural networks fitted to your data (there are several of them).

```
library(forecast)
fit <- nnetar(lynx)
str(fit)
str(fit$model[[1]])
summary( fit$model[[1]] )
# a 8-4-1 network with 41 weights
# options were - linear output units 
#  b->h1 i1->h1 i2->h1 i3->h1 i4->h1 i5->h1 i6->h1 i7->h1 i8->h1 
#   2.99  -7.31   3.90  -2.63  -1.48   4.30   2.57   2.77  -9.40 
#  b->h2 i1->h2 i2->h2 i3->h2 i4->h2 i5->h2 i6->h2 i7->h2 i8->h2 
#  -0.23  -1.42  -1.27   0.75   2.48   1.12   0.01  -2.79  -2.35 
#  b->h3 i1->h3 i2->h3 i3->h3 i4->h3 i5->h3 i6->h3 i7->h3 i8->h3 
#   3.30  -1.43  -0.79   7.44  -0.42   1.12  -5.36  15.61  -5.17 
#  b->h4 i1->h4 i2->h4 i3->h4 i4->h4 i5->h4 i6->h4 i7->h4 i8->h4 
#   2.49   6.25  -7.01   7.06  -0.99   1.80  -0.55   5.53  -5.31 
#  b->o h1->o h2->o h3->o h4->o 
#  2.31 -0.47 -0.16 -4.07  2.37 
fit$model[[1]]$wts
#  [1]  2.98730023 -7.30926809  3.89674784 -2.63077534 -1.48084101  4.30309382
#  [7]  2.57150487  2.76947222 -9.40136188 -0.23053466 -1.41876993 -1.26569624
# [13]  0.75035031  2.48057839  1.11969186  0.01107485 -2.79027580 -2.35033702
# [19]  3.29874907 -1.43432740 -0.79437302  7.43590968 -0.42005316  1.12337542
# [25] -5.35698080 15.61077915 -5.16566644  2.49343460  6.25330958 -7.00554826
# [31]  7.05694732 -0.99034344  1.80374167 -0.55078148  5.52887784 -5.31445324
# [37]  2.31407224 -0.46995772 -0.15824823 -4.06939514  2.36781125
```